# Where to initialize a private variable in Unity C# that requires access to scene hierarchy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene, prefab

I have a "Manager" type class called PlayerManager and I'd like to initialize an object for it in a different class/object using FindObjectOfType(). My understanding is that this searches the current scene hierarchy to find an object that has this specific script.

I use this line of code on a prefab that gets generated in the scene instead of being there from the beginning. The variable is private. Sometimes the object cannot be found because I am using this line on Start() function so I am assuming that the "FindObjectOfType" line is called before it can actually search for the object, therefore finding nothing there.

I thought of using this on Update() instead and check if the object is null first so it doesn't loop. I don't know if this is a good practice but it doesn't "feel right".

What would be the ideal way of doing this if I don't want to use a public or [SerializeField] Variable?

Comment: You guessed right, `Update()` has a different purpose and should not be used like that. But please, elaborate, what is the reason that you don't want private serialized fields or turning them public? If you need to set a variable in a different instance, that is what a public variable is for. If you want to only access it, use `public readonly` or getter properties. An alternative is using get or set functions, but that's what properties are for mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, using `FindType` codes is not optimal at all, and using this code in `Update` is even worse. In this case, you must specify the Manager in the `Spawner` object (for example, gun...) and after instantiate, refer the created game object to the manager.

---

Although you haven't posted any code in your question. But I will show you an example how to avoid `Find`. As you can see, put a determining spawn object event in the manager.

```cs
public class Manager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Bullet spawned; // for example type of Bullet
    public void SetSpawnedObject(Bullet _spawned)
    {
        spawned = _spawned;
    }
}
```

Right after the instantiate is done, you should run your event. This event can be anything.

```cs
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Manager _manager;
    public Bullet bullet;
    
    public void Spawn()
    {
        var _newBullet = Instantiate(bullet);
        _manager.SetSpawnedObject(_newBullet); // set new Bullet to manager after instantiating..
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up going for an alteration of this solution. My class responsible for the generation of the player among other things calls a public function now in order to set the appropriate variables. The generation class already has the references since it is the one that instantiates the game objects in the first place, making it easy to gain access to their script components. 

This also removes the FindObjectOfType line which I understand can be problematic if used all over the place and should ideally be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate your game object in `Awake()` and then call `FindObjectOfType()` method in `Start()`.

or

You can use Coroutines to fetch instances after a certain amount of time. This delay will allow you to get what you're looking for after its created.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not you can call `yield return null` within the `Start()` function (without calling a Coroutine).  I needed to do this some time ago for the same reasons.

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    // wait 2 frames
    yield return null;
    yield return null;

    FindObjectOfType(bob);
}
```

Comment: You can't just put `yield return null;` in a `void Start()`, because it's a function and can't yield. However, you can turn Start *into* a coroutine by replacing `void` with `IEnumerator` and it will still be called on the first frame, just like a regular Start function would.

Comment: You are correct.